# Get data from two tables(join) with linq and return result into view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to get data from Projects(which have CourseId) and related CourseName from Courses table.

I have written following code:

```
var projects = from n in db.Projects
                       join c in db.Courses on n.CourseId equals c.ID
                       orderby n.Name
                       select new { Project = n, Course = c };

        return View(projects.ToList());
```

and I get error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[ProjectManager.Models.Project,ProjectManager.Models.Course]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ProjectManager.Models.Project]'.

What I need to do in Controller and in View to display this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an anonymous type into your view, but the view is declared as taking an `IEnumerable<Project>`.

You should remove the `@model` declaration from the view to make it use a `dynamic` model.